# curl -o- option

Tags: bash, curl

I intended to download `nvm` from https://github.com/creationix/nvm when I stumbled upon the following command:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash`

Does anyone know the meaning of the dash behind `-o`? It isn't mentioned in the man pages, nor could I find any clue. I also tried it without the `-o-`option and it still works, which is why I'm wondering what it could mean?

Comment: Same meaning as a dash has in `cat -` or other standard/conventional cases where a filename would otherwise be expected.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`curl`'s `-o` option gives you the ability to specify an output file. `-` in this context refers to the standard output(`stdout`), which means `curl` will output its response to the the standard output plugged as standard input to the `bash` invocation.

In this context it could have been omitted as outputting to `stdout` is `curl`'s standard behavior.

As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) mentions, it can become useful when you're downloading multiple ressources at the same time and want to display only one of them on `stdout` :

```
curl -o- -o fileA -o fileB url1 url2 url3
```

In this case `url1` will be output to `stdout`, `url2` to `fileA` and `url3` to `fileB`.

Note that this could still be avoided since ressources without a matching output specification will be output to `stdout`. The following command would behave the same as the previous one :

```
curl -o fileA -o fileB url2 url3 url1
```

Comment: Since `-o` can be used once per URL, it might be useful as a way to write some URLs to files, and others to standard output:  `curl -o url1.html -o - -o url3.html  "$URL1" "$URL2" "$URL3"`.

Comment: @chepner thanks, I thought I had once used that for a good reason but couldn't remember how.